# how to add a ionic plugin in a m-generator-ionic project

Tags: plugins, ionic-framework

i would like to use the following QR-code plugin in my "m-generator-ionic" project: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/platform/barcode/

in ionic framework, the command to be executed to install it is

```
$ ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
```

what is the equivalent in the m-generator-ionic world ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to [`generator-m-ionic`](https://github.com/mwaylabs/generator-m-ionic).

You can find a guide [here](https://github.com/mwaylabs/generator-m-ionic/blob/34d5e0f56106652e94739a66514b8a2f87f2bf81/docs/start/development_intro.md#using-the-cordova-cli) which describes how to write any cordova statement.

In your specific case this would be

```
$ gulp --cordova 'plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner'
```

And if you want to save it to your config.xml:

```
$ gulp --cordova 'plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner --save'
```

Let me know if this was helpful.